# loading json file jquery $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a json file `myfile.json` .

how can I load it into `data:myfile`

```
  $(function() {
      var myfile = $.getJSON("/myfile.json", function(data){

   });
    $("#tags").tags().autofill({
      data:myfile <--- load it here--->
    });
  });
```

Update. The json file contains the following

```
["Mystic-VEN001","D&D-VEN002","Wall-Mart-VEN003"]
```

what i want is for the data to be loaded like this

```
data: ["Mystic-VEN001","D&D-VEN002","Wall-Mart-VEN003"]
```

Comment: have you read the info from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ ?

Comment: `data: data`...`data:myfile`...what is this supposed to be? It's not Javascript, or at least not outside the context of declaring an object literal. What do you actually want to do with the JSON data? I guess you've maybe got an object called `data` with a property called `myfile`? In that case, simple JS syntax to reference a property and assign a variable to it...`data.myfile = someOtherVariable`. Any simply JS tutorial will show this kind of thing. BTW that's not how you use $.getJSON either. It's async so you need a calback. Stop guessing syntax and commands and read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

man. I think you need to use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('youjsonfile.json', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```